# how to start with unmanaged vps?

Tags: vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job)

I have a managed VPS, so whatever i need i can just ask my support, and they will do it for me.

Now i plan to migrate to unmanaged VPS, so i need some guides, tips on how and where to start learning. I will have more specific questions once i start using it, but now i just need some general answers about this topic.

Thanks.

Update:

Ok, i have decided to go for unmanaged VPS with cPanel. OS is CentOS-5.

I contacted support only for some small(i think) things like creating new account in whm, some database importing, installing new software(rare)...

What i will be using is apache, php, mysql. I think i will be able to cope with upgrading to new versions, so the thing that interests me the most is security i guess.

Comment: If you already have a managed VPS and your ISP's support staff installs and configures everything for you, why migrate to an unmanaged VPS at all?

Comment: The Internet/ Serverfault / Amazon has tips and guides for the Operating System you forgot to mention and the application(s) you also didnt mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is like saying: *I've only gone out on the ocean before on a boat. I want to swim by myself now, can someone give me any tips or guides on how to swim?*

You need to get the unmanaged VPS before migrating and then read the multiple other posts on here and other sides. Google "How to learn system administration". You did not mention what OS or anything else so it is hard to really give you any tips but here are questions that were asked before:

- [How to learn VPS for newbies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41699/how-to-learn-master-tutorials-for-managing-a-vps-newbie-vps-user)
- [The best way to learn linux/apache administration?](https://serverfault.com/questions/42082/the-best-way-to-learning-linux-apache-server-administration)
- [How to gain system administration skills?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19621/how-to-gain-system-adminstration-skills)
- [Becoming good at server admin-ing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/70238/becoming-good-at-server-admin-ing)
- [and more...](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/learning)

Answer (score 0):

My main tip would be to learn *before* you have an unmanaged VPS, or at least before you have any production systems on the unmanaged service. Unless you are confident that you can managed the server and maintain its security you would be putting your production systems/data at risk. Perhaps you could run both systems side-by-side for a while, using the unmanaged one as a testing environment for your learning process. You don't even need to rent a VPS to do this: you could instead install the relevant software (licensing arrangements permitting: you don't state what software you are using or planning to use so I can only guess there) in a VM on your local machine/network.

The main thing you will need to learn is how to manage and secure your OS and any services (such as control panels) you have running on it. I can't give more specific details here as you don't state anything about the software (OS and other services) that you are using or intend to use.

Also, what sort of things do you normally need to contact support for? This info will help us both given specific pointers or allow us to gauge your current level of experience and tailor generic advice accordingly.

Comment: I updated my question with a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

Unmanaged VPS...

In any system trouble, they will say use ssh to connect and fix the files.

So first learn how to do ssh, and navigate around folders and look for httpd.conf, my.cnf files and how to edit, update and restart each services.  Also figure out how to start the VPS, when WHM fails